# Sending a Get Request (to the source site) Before Answering a Post Request

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, plesk

I am testing a controlling algorithm. I am using windows-hosting/plesk and c#.
I am having a problem like this:

My hosting account is called myhosting.com.

My sites in this account,

1. myhosting.com , files in httpdocs folder
2. second.com , files in second.com folder
3. controller.com , files in controller.com folder

Normal running process:

1. A page on second.com sends an HTTP-POST request to a page on controller.com,
   for to get a string.
2. Before controller.com responds to the POST request, sends an HTTP-GET request
   to an another page on second.com, for to get the control string.
3. The page on controller.com, because the string it receives with GET is correct
   it responds positively to the POST request in the first step.

Incorrect operation (performing normal operation from myhosting.com):

1. A page on myhosting.com sends an HTTP-POST request to a page on controller.com,
   for to get a string.
2. Before controller.com responds to the POST request, sends an HTTP-GET request
   to an another page on myhosting.com, for to get the control string.
3. According to the log records, myhosting.com responded to the GET request
   although, the page on controller.com has not yet evaluated the GET's response,
   it answers the POST request in the first step with the HTTP 500 error. The error
   cannot catch with try/catch.

Where does the error come from? Access permissions? Verb settings? It was working
initially. I deleted the index.aspx from the default doc list in the myhosting.com
and unwittingly did another action, then the error started to occur.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Failed Request Tracing. The reply to the post message contains no error details. With this method, error details can be obtained.